# Why does a href # jump to homepage instead of div id?

Tags: html

I want to jump to a section within a html page using the tag:

```
<a href="#details">example</a>
```

The section id:

```
<div id="details"></div>
<section id="viewad-details">
```

The page itself contains a base tag which I need to keep:

```
<base href=//domain.com/">
```

Doctype (pretty old legacy)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Somehow this does not work and a click on the link loads the homepage instead of jumping to the div id. I also intended originally to jump to the section but this had the same effect.

How can this feature be implemented while keeping the base tag in place?

Comment: "I also intended originally to jump to the section but this had the same effect."-- What do you mean by this?

Comment: Does the `href` attribute contain `#details` (as the code says) or `/#details` as you final sentence says?

Comment: What version of HTML are you using?  I tried the code with HTML5 and it worked fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean the <section> tag which is part of my app and I wanted to link originaly to that place without adding an additional "a name" tag or "div" tag. I also updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is feasible with HTML5 as below code demonstrates:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>


<body>
<a href="#details">example</a>
<div id="ipsum" style="width: 200px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar maximus sem a condimentum. Nunc sapien arcu, mollis et diam eu, tempor euismod orci. Sed blandit, erat quis laoreet vehicula, diam ipsum tempor turpis, vel suscipit nisl urna euismod orci. Nulla rutrum efficitur nisi et molestie. Curabitur a sollicitudin justo. Curabitur nunc ligula, malesuada pharetra pulvinar vitae, maximus in nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce rhoncus molestie turpis, quis gravida mauris dictum vel. Suspendisse semper est sed tortor pretium, eget tincidunt massa viverra. Donec et ullamcorper lorem. Cras posuere quam lorem, vitae fringilla diam posuere in. Vivamus et porta enim, ac hendrerit lacus.

Mauris non odio at odio elementum consequat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi non ligula feugiat, tincidunt risus sit amet, blandit elit. Sed eu fermentum purus. Nam maximus nunc elementum, fermentum neque sit amet, vulputate lorem. Sed nec urna quis nisi vulputate iaculis ac in nisl. Sed convallis leo vitae efficitur scelerisque. In dictum justo at diam convallis, ut sagittis neque cursus. Phasellus viverra, risus at cursus cursus, est tellus ullamcorper arcu, id pharetra ligula magna vel leo. Cras libero mi, aliquet a aliquam nec, euismod nec felis. Vivamus ac arcu id lectus ultricies tincidunt quis iaculis velit. Nam porttitor laoreet eros, eu laoreet massa fermentum a. Pellentesque cursus finibus leo, non interdum ligula.

</div>
<div id="details" style="background:beige;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red">All the details</div>
<section id="viewad-details">

</body>
</html>
```

The div entitled "details" also scrolls into focus in HTML 4.01.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#details">example</a>
<div id="ipsum" style="width: 200px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar maximus sem a condimentum. Nunc sapien arcu, mollis et diam eu, tempor euismod orci. Sed blandit, erat quis laoreet vehicula, diam ipsum tempor turpis, vel suscipit nisl urna euismod orci. Nulla rutrum efficitur nisi et molestie. Curabitur a sollicitudin justo. Curabitur nunc ligula, malesuada pharetra pulvinar vitae, maximus in nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce rhoncus molestie turpis, quis gravida mauris dictum vel. Suspendisse semper est sed tortor pretium, eget tincidunt massa viverra. Donec et ullamcorper lorem. Cras posuere quam lorem, vitae fringilla diam posuere in. Vivamus et porta enim, ac hendrerit lacus.

Mauris non odio at odio elementum consequat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi non ligula feugiat, tincidunt risus sit amet, blandit elit. Sed eu fermentum purus. Nam maximus nunc elementum, fermentum neque sit amet, vulputate lorem. Sed nec urna quis nisi vulputate iaculis ac in nisl. Sed convallis leo vitae efficitur scelerisque. In dictum justo at diam convallis, ut sagittis neque cursus. Phasellus viverra, risus at cursus cursus, est tellus ullamcorper arcu, id pharetra ligula magna vel leo. Cras libero mi, aliquet a aliquam nec, euismod nec felis. Vivamus ac arcu id lectus ultricies tincidunt quis iaculis velit. Nam porttitor laoreet eros, eu laoreet massa fermentum a. Pellentesque cursus finibus leo, non interdum ligula.


</div>
<div id="details" style="background:cyan;width:200px;height:150px;border:1px solid red">All the details</div>
<section id="viewad-details">

</body>
</html>
```

The BASE tag however appears to be the proverbial fly in the ointment.  Consider the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 <title>Untitled</title>
<base href="https://www.example.com"> 
</head>

<body>
<a href="#details">example</a>
<div id="ipsum" style="width: 200px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar maximus sem a condimentum. Nunc sapien arcu, mollis et diam eu, tempor euismod orci. Sed blandit, erat quis laoreet vehicula, diam ipsum tempor turpis, vel suscipit nisl urna euismod orci. Nulla rutrum efficitur nisi et molestie. Curabitur a sollicitudin justo. Curabitur nunc ligula, malesuada pharetra pulvinar vitae, maximus in nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce rhoncus molestie turpis, quis gravida mauris dictum vel. Suspendisse semper est sed tortor pretium, eget tincidunt massa viverra. Donec et ullamcorper lorem. Cras posuere quam lorem, vitae fringilla diam posuere in. Vivamus et porta enim, ac hendrerit lacus.

Mauris non odio at odio elementum consequat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi non ligula feugiat, tincidunt risus sit amet, blandit elit. Sed eu fermentum purus. Nam maximus nunc elementum, fermentum neque sit amet, vulputate lorem. Sed nec urna quis nisi vulputate iaculis ac in nisl. Sed convallis leo vitae efficitur scelerisque. In dictum justo at diam convallis, ut sagittis neque cursus. Phasellus viverra, risus at cursus cursus, est tellus ullamcorper arcu, id pharetra ligula magna vel leo. Cras libero mi, aliquet a aliquam nec, euismod nec felis. Vivamus ac arcu id lectus ultricies tincidunt quis iaculis velit. Nam porttitor laoreet eros, eu laoreet massa fermentum a. Pellentesque cursus finibus leo, non interdum ligula.

</div>
<div id="details" style="background:#ffdede;width:200px;height:140px;border:1px solid red">All the details</div>
<section id="viewad-details">

</body>
</html>
```

Owing to the href value of the BASE tag, all relative urls are judged to be in the context of domain example.com.  As a result #details refers not to a portion of the current page but is a fragment of the url https://www.example.com#details.

A solution suggested [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399) recommends using an absolute url for the anchor tag.  Here's what worked on my local server with the following BASE and ANCHOR tags:

```
<base href="https://www.example.com">
<!-- other HTML -->
<a href="http://localhost/exp/div401Base.html#details">eXample</a>
```

When the user clicks the link the DIV entitled details scrolls into view for the current page and thereby avoids a redirect to url https://example.com#details.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I added info to my question regarding doctype and base tag which might be a reason why it does not work in my environment.

Comment: @merlin You're welcome. Tried the body portion in HTML 4.01 on my local web server and it also worked fine.  I suspect the issue may be related to the BASE tag.

Comment: Most likely, unfortunatelly I need to keep the base tag in place. Do you see a way doing this with base tag in place?

Comment: @merlin Use an absolute URL in the anchor tag; see my expanded answer.

Comment: Sometimes things are two obvious to see! Thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the link to work with the `#` sign, the code needs to have an anchor link's "name" property.

```
<a name="details"><section id="viewad-details"></a>
```

The [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) defines this as a feature of HTML [Anchor tags](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html):

> NAME
>   OPTIONAL. If present, the attribute NAME allows the anchor to be the destination of a link. The value of the attribute is an identifier for the anchor. Identifiers are arbitrary strings but must be unique within the HTML document. Another document can then make a reference explicitly to this anchor by putting the identifier after the address, separated by a hash sign.

Comment: Not anymore. [The `name` attribute was removed in HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Comment: That's interesting, but HTML 4 is still supported in every modern browser for backwards compatibility purposes. It still works! https://caniuse.com/#search=HTML4%20elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 60
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

section {
  min-height: 800px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.section1 {
  background: #96CEB4;
}

.section2 {
  background: #FF6F69;
}

.section3 {
  background: #FFCC5C;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#1">Section1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#2">Section2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#3">Section3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <section class="section1" id="1">
      <h1>Section1</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section2" id="2">
      <h1>Section2</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section3" id="3">
      <h1>Section3</h1>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jquery is completely unnecessary here .. .

Comment: it's just an add-on if you want but you can get rid of it anytime.

Comment: but that's not what the question (question is tagged with just `html`) is about ... not everyone wants to use jQuery ...